# ggplot2 map comes out blank with only title and legend R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'am trying to make maps using ggplot2. Dot maps work fine but choropleth maps just come out blank.

```
library(broom)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

philly_df <- tidy(philly)
head(philly_df)

philly$polyID <- sapply(slot(philly, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
philly_df <- merge(philly_df, philly, by.x = "id", by.y="polyID")
head(philly_df)

# because my polygon number grows from 72 to up to 6000 with repeated entries,
#  use distinct to have them back to 72
distinct(philly_df, id, .keep_all = TRUE)

# Generate the data to plot
philly_df <- merge(philly_df, Death_U5, by.x = "DIS_NAME", by.y="District")
head(philly_df)

# when I plot the map, it gives error:
# "Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot"
# and shows only title and legend but no map

ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = philly_df,        
                 aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = cut_number(deathU5_Q1, 5))) +
    scale_fill_brewer("deaths", palette = "OrRd") +
    ggtitle("under 5 malaria deaths for Q1 Philly") + 
    theme(line = element_blank(),           
          axis.text=element_blank(),            
          axis.title=element_blank(),               
          panel.background = element_blank())           
    coord_equal()
```

Comment: Where does `philly` come from? Is it in a package or your own data? If it's the latter, can you share it so we can reproduce the error? By the way, you're missing a `+` between your `theme` and `coord_equal`...

Comment: Post an example of your data. Also, if you're plotting maps, consider the use of `geom_map`; with it, you don't need to merge your data into the polygons object; your data just need to have the id column.

Comment: Thank you @Lyngbakr and @ Carlos Eduardo Lagosta. The insight helped. It worked and has displayed the map. I cannot tell what may have been the issue coz with and without the mentioned +, it still displayed. I really appreciate your check. When I reran the code to confirm the missing +, then the map appeared.  I had been on this issue for two days now... but glad it is resolved